# Jquery target specific element - dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a simple jquery dropdown menu but when i click a dropdown it opens all my dropdown menus, what do i need to add to my code to make it so it only targets the specific element clicked and only opens that dropdown menu?

Apologies if this has been asked before.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.parent').click(function() {
    $('.sub-menu').slideToggle(400);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu-1">
  <li class="parent dropdown"><a class="parent">Link</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="" class="parent">Link</a></li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="" class="parent">Link</a></li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="" class="parent">Link</a></li>
  <li class="parent dropdown"><a class="parent">Link</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you're selecting all the `.sub-menu` elements in the DOM. You need to retrieve only those which are siblings of the clicked `.parent` using the `this` keyword and `next()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.parent').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideToggle(400);
  });
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML:

<ul class="menu-1">
  <li class="parent dropdown">
    <a class="parent" href="#">Link</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="" class="parent">Link</a></li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="" class="parent">Link</a></li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="" class="parent">Link</a></li>
  <li class="parent dropdown">
    <a class="parent" href="#">Link</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Also note the use of `preventDefault()` to stop the parent link causing a page redirect.

Comment: In case there are elements between `a` and `ul` you can use this: `$('.sub-menu', $(this).parent()).slideToggle(400);`

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('a.parent').click(function(e) {
        $(e.target).closest('li').find('.sub-menu').slideToggle(400);
    });
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu-1">
  <li class="parent dropdown"><a class="parent">Link</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="" class="parent">Link</a></li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="" class="parent">Link</a></li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="" class="parent">Link</a></li>
  <li class="parent dropdown"><a class="parent">Link</a></li>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

In your event handler, you look for all elements with sub-menu class. You should update your selector to find only the menu related to your link.

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('a.parent').click(function(e) {
        $(e.target).closest('li').find('.sub-menu').slideToggle(400);
    });
});
```

Comment: You can also use the following instead of `closest` and `find`: `$('.sub-menu', $(this).parent()).slideToggle(400);`

Answer (score 0):

Use this operator for achieving this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.parent').click(function() {
    $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideToggle(400);
    });
});
```